# JUnit Test Case for Aggregation

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have Service class which contains Aggregation method like following:

```java
public List<Demo> demo() {

        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                Aggregation.project().and(month("$date")).as("month"),
                Aggregation.group("$month").count().as("count"),
                project("count").and("month").previousOperation(),
                Aggregation.match(where("month").is(2)));

        List<Demo> demo=  mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "demo",Demo.class).getMappedResults();
        System.out.println(demo.size());
        return demo;
    }
```

when I have Execute this method then System.out.println() gives 2 result that is correct.
I have wrote JUnit test case for above method:

```java
  @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class DemoServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    DemoService demoService;

    @Test
    public void demoTest(){

        List<Demo> demo= demoService.demo();
        Assert.assertEquals(1, demo.size());
    }
}
```

When I execute test method then system.out.println() returns 1 result instead of 2 result. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: You need to explain how you are creating `demoService` in your test class, and how its dependencies are created. Also what is `orders`?

Comment: @tgdavies  I have Updated My Code